# How to bind to constant in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

How to bind to constant in JavaFX?

I found a way like

```
myObject.myIntegerProperty().bind(new IntegerBinding() {
   @Override
   protected int computeValue() {
      return 2;
   }
});
```

but it looks too excessive.

Is there any shorted way?

Comment: Why would you bind to a constant? Wouldn't you just do `myObject.myIntegerProperty().set(2);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [James_D pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005107/how-to-bind-to-constant-in-javafx#comment67288088_40005107): there's no need to create a binding to a constant, simply initialize the property with the given value. However, I'd suggest to use a [`ReadOnlyIntegerProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerProperty.html) to ensure that the property isn't modified somewhere else:

```java
public final class MyClass {

    private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper myInteger = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(2);

    public int getMyInteger() {
        return myInteger.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty myIntegerProperty() {
        return myInteger.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

}
```

Note that the class should be `final` [according to Jonathan Giles](http://fxexperience.com/2016/10/javafx-links-of-the-week-october-24-2/):

> Jeff Frieson has an article about [read-only properties in JavaFX](http://www.javaworld.com/article/3133172/learn-java/read-only-properties-in-javafx-8.html#tk.rss_all). The article lacks a little clarity, so I was a little reticent to include it. The biggest issue is the fact that the methods are not final (although the class is, but I worry people won’t notice this). The methods not being final provides a huge issue if subclasses try to override the getter / setter methods and include logic (because then there are two code paths – setting via the setter and setting via the property method – and they do not overlap, resulting in unexpected behaviour at runtime. The standard rule applies – when creating getter / setter / property methods, always make them final.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative could be

```
Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> 2)
```

This creates an IntegerBinding which evaluates to 2 as soon as needed.

It doesn't invalidate at all (as there are no dependencies given), so it remains at this value forever.